# Process XML file multiple times

Tags: java, xml

I have a JAVA class in which I have implemented parsing of XML using the DOM parser. The XML file that is parsed is a configuration file which has configuration params. Any request coming to my website will be redirected based on the information that is returned from this xml file. I have 2 questions around this

1) I would like to do the file parsing only once and not every time. Since, DOM parser loads the xml into memory after the first time I would like to know how to check if the file is already available in the memory? so that the following is not called everytime

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new File(sFpath));
```

2) If the xml file changes how do I make sure the new chaged xml file is re-loaded.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DOM is an intermediate format - parse it in some application-specific (and friendly) object structure, and stash that in a singleton. You don't want to go hunting through a DOM for every web request. Then, regularly (every x minutes or y web requests), check whether the file has been updated, re-parse it, and update your singleton.

Comment: I am looking into using this method of using a singleton for this purpose. The class will be accessible from servlets and JSPs. I am able to access it from servlet but how do I access the singleton from JSP?

Answer (score 0):

The reading of file should be implemented separately,i mean not along with the code that you handle requests or maybe in [static initialization block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)  and then you can use a file watcher to detect file changes.Options for file watching :

1. [File Watcher](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0490.html)
2. [WatchService API(Java 7)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)
3. [JFileNotify](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfilenotify/)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the DOM in application memory just like any other data - the details depend on what application server / framework you are using. But DOM is a poor choice, not just because of its clumsy API, but also because DOM is not thread-safe, so all access would need to be synchronized. You're better off with a tree model that is read-only once parsed. Consider using Saxon and XPath/XQuery for this - load the tree once into a read only Saxon tree that can then be repeatedly accessed using XPath or XQuery, invoked from your Java application.

Creating Java classes to represent your configuration data more explicitly, as suggested by cdegroot, is an alternative, but not really necessary in my view. It will probably involve more work for you each time you add something to the configuration file.